# Speeding up while loop using xlwings

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, xlwings

As the title says, I am using a while loop (below) to iterate through an excel sheet with 78,000+ rows of data. I have roughly 65 different conditions in the if statement (not showing all for sake of what I'm doing) and was wondering if there was a good way to speed this process up. Currently the runtime is ~4 hours and I personally feel like it can be sped up but I am unsure where to start.

```
while i <= lastRow:
      if sheet.range('A' + str(i)).value == 'DLQ' or sheet.range('A' + str(i)).value == 'DLZ' + (another 63 conditions):
           i = i + 1
           lastRow = wb.sheets[0].range('A' + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
      else:
           xw.Range(str(i) + ':' + str(i)).delete(shift='up').row
```

I would like to use a for loop but the iteration doesn't work with what I am trying to do. If you can help me make this loop more efficient I would really appreciate it!

Comment: `sheet.range('A' + str(i)).value in ["DLQ", "DLZ", ....]` would certainly clean things up visually. I would also define the list outside the loop myself

Comment: Is `lastrow` always the same for each iteration?

Comment: @jonSG , I just debugged, realized the process wasn't finishing because once it reached the end of the cells with data in them, i (index) didn't continue to iterate so the process became infinite. Moved ```lastRow = wb.sheets...``` into the else statement and that seems to work. So to answer your question no, lastRow is constantly updated now.

Comment: @jonSG , the program runs incredibly efficient now, like light years in comparison just from the list change. Thank you so much for that. From ~4-5 hours to less than an hour